# pentaho insert/update performance slow

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

i'm trying to make an ETL process like this :

```
ID | NAME | MARKS | START_DATE | END_DATE  | DELETE_FLAG
1  |SATISH| 90    | 2021/03/31 | 9999/12/31| 0
2  |KUMAR | 100   | 2021/03/31 | 9999/12/31| 0
```

and then SATISH MARKS GOT HIGHER

```
ID | NAME | MARKS | START_DATE | END_DATE  | DELETE_FLAG
1  |SATISH| 90    | 2021/03/31 | 2021/04/11| 0
2  |KUMAR | 100   | 2021/03/31 | 9999/12/31| 0
1  |SATISH| 100   | 11/04/2021 | 9999/12/31| 0
```

Then in the date 2021/04/12 SATISH records from STUDENT TABLE not exist (physically deleted). it will become like this

```
ID | NAME | MARKS | START_DATE | END_DATE  | DELETE_FLAG
1  |SATISH| 90    | 2021/03/31 | 2021/04/11| 1
2  |KUMAR | 100   | 2021/03/31 | 9999/12/31| 0
1  |SATISH| 100   | 11/04/2021 | 2021/04/12| 1
```

And already got it, but the issue was the performance, i can only get it to 17 r/s
too much too slow..
i'm doing this with my local computer, and the db is in the server.

but i think it won't make that much of different, because i had to load 4 millions records later, someone has nay idea how do i improve this?

this is my pentaho transformation :https://filebin.net/vghhosa61eca46vd
[image: performance]

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the "performance" tab once the execution has completed?

Comment: Unfortunately that question has not an easy answer. You'll have to check the performance of each step to see where the delay is coming from, and yes, executing Pentaho in your PC and modifying a table in the server can be one of the reasons, depending on the quality of the network between your PC and the server. If every Update and Insert/update step in your screenshot try to modify the same table, it can also be a bottleneck because of locks on the table. The way the database is modeled can be an issue too (does adding an index to the target table improve performance?) ...